# Expand the imagery range to more than one tile in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, tiles, metes-and-bounds

I am creating a map layer in Google Earth Engine using Sentinel-2 data and no matter what I set my bounds too I can only get it to display one tile. I know that I have mapped things before that aren't restricted so much with their range.

Is this a Sentinel-2 artifact or something else?

Specifically, I have a range of sites that fall in three different tiles but I want to display them all without manually having to make three different maps to ensure I am using the same image date across all of them.

```
var map = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
          .filterBounds(bounds1) //Whether I make this bounds or point it doesn't cover the whole area of interest.
          .filterDate('2020-06-15', '2020-08-25')
          .sort("CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESMENT")
          .first();

 Map.addLayer(NDVI,
          {
              min: -1,
              max: 1,
              palette: vegPalette
          },
          'NDVI Barrow');
```

`bounds1` right now is just a point, but I also have a table variable that is the specific quadrants of all the sites. When I make that the bounds it makes no difference.

Per the comment below, I tried this:
var bounds =
ee.Geometry.MultiPoint(
[[[-156.45876963735367,70.4062237170219],
[-155.40957530141617,70.37672835672139],
[-155.65599795285246,70.09786590712172],
[-157.32119639516617,70.48895122857022]]]);

But it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a polygon for filtering scenes or filter by metadata:

Option 1:

```
var bounds1 = 
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-114.1404296875, 35.21449970953598],
          [-114.1404296875, 34.27566862728803],
          [-107.5486328125, 34.27566862728803],
          [-107.5486328125, 35.21449970953598]]], null, false);

var map = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
          .filterBounds(bounds1)
          .filterDate('2020-06-15', '2020-08-25')
          .sort("CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESMENT");
```

Option 2 (didn't choose all the tiles tho):

```
var map = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
       .filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('MGRS_TILE','12SXC'),
          ee.Filter.eq('MGRS_TILE','12SYE'),
          ee.Filter.eq('MGRS_TILE','13SBV'),
          ee.Filter.eq('MGRS_TILE','12SWE'),
          ee.Filter.eq('MGRS_TILE','12SWC'),
          ee.Filter.eq('MGRS_TILE','12SUE'),
          ee.Filter.eq('MGRS_TILE','12SQT'),
          ee.Filter.eq('MGRS_TILE','12STC')))
          .filterDate('2020-06-15', '2020-08-25')
          .sort("CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESMENT");
```

The easiest approach is option 1

Comment: Thanks @aldo_tapia. I had tried the first option before but it doesn't work. It just chooses one of the coordinates and has a tile that that one point is in. Could you explain a little more about option 2? Where do you get the tile information and numbers?

Comment: Sure, sentinel scenes are around 290 km wide, but distributed in 100x100 km tiles. So for one date, you need to process from one to many tiles to get all the data you need. These tiles are based on the Military Grid Reference System (hence, MGRS), so you need to identify which tiles you need to choose for your area. Download [this shapefile](https://github.com/justinelliotmeyers/Sentinel-2-Shapefile-Index) and identify which tiles you need to filter

Answer (score 0):

The `filterBounds` method will select any image that partially intersects your geometry. By selecting just the `first` image from the filtered collection, you get a single image that only covers one of your points. Trying to find one image that covers all of your points would be tricky (or impossible), but combining *all* of the images that match your criteria to [make a single composite image](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/ic_composite_mosaic) is easy.

Just replace `first` with something like [`mosaic`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-imagecollection-mosaic) or [`median`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-imagecollection-median). The result will contain pixels from multiple images and cover all of your points.

```
var map = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
          .filterBounds(bounds1)
          .filterDate('2020-06-15', '2020-08-25')
          .sort("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", false)
          .mosaic();
```

Comment: Thanks so much Aaron Zuspan. It did work and now the image covers the whole area which is great however, it is totally unusable because the cloud coverage is so bad. Do you have any suggestions for that? My understanding was the first. () was selecting the best image cloud coverage wise. Do I have to choose one over the other?

Comment: I made a minor edit to my answer that should help the cloud cover. `mosaic` puts the last images on top (the opposite of `first`), so I changed the sort order to put the least cloudy images on top. I also sorted by `CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE` instead of `CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT` which did a much better job. For the best results, you could apply [pixel-level cloud masking](https://medium.com/google-earth/more-accurate-and-flexible-cloud-masking-for-sentinel-2-images-766897a9ba5f).